Will this right angle PCIe 5 power adaptor work with the RTX 4070 Super?
I'm building a small form factor PC in the Fractal Terra case. I am using the Asus RTX 4070 Super GPU and the included PCI adapter is too tall and I can't put the lid of the case:

I found this:
https://www.amazon.com/Agtray-Extender-12VHPWR-Extension-Compatible/dp/B0BZRYXW1J
But I'm not certain if this is fully compatible with the GPU and is wired the same as stock adapter.
I tried to use the stock adapter by taking the tape off to see if I can get a better bend. I found this strange configuration of wires, including 3 of which look like they are not connected (they look like they have a clean cut):

I thought I may have damaged it when I took off the tape, but when I peel back the external sheathing, I don't see any other wires the three cut wires would have been connected it. If I can bend these enough to get the lid to close without the tape, is this safe to use with those 3 disconnected wires?

Those extenders and right angle adapters are unsafe. Those adapters are prone to melting. Wires probably never were connected.

As mentioned, they were cut before you opened it. Look carefully at your good photo; the ends were clipped neatly, with a flat surface. Bending, then taping (or using heat-shrink tubing) would be better than adding a 90° elbow.
